# C++11 HOWTO template aliasing for function pointers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

*I need the code to compile on Visual Studio 2013*

Originally I had:

```
class P
{
    typedef void* (P::*FunctionPtr)(void);
    typedef void* (*T_ptr)(void*);

    private:    
        T_ptr getCompatibleFunctionPointer(FunctionPtr funcPtr);
        T_ptr m_t_ptr;

    public:
        [omitting constructors, etc]
}
```

Now, adding templates requires the keyword using so I tried:

```
typedef  void* (*T_ptr)(void*);

//tried this:
template<typename objectThread>
using FunctionPtr = void(P<objectThread>::*)(void);
//also tried:
template<typename objectThread>
using FunctionPtr = void(P< typename objectThread>::*)(void);
//also tried:
template<typename objectThread>
using FunctionPtr = void(P< typename objectThread>*)(void);

template<typename objectThread>
class P{


private:

    template<typename objectThread>
    T_ptr P<objectThread>::getCompatibleFunctionPointer(FunctionPtr funcPtr) {}
    T_ptr m_t_ptr;

};
```

I cannot find a way of achieving what I need. I do need to keep the templates and cannot use Boost (just in case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it just in class with

```
using FunctionPtr = void(P<objectThread>::*)();
```

and that just use it in class.

So, your code will be just

```
template<typename objectThread>
class P{
    using T_ptr = void*(*)(void*);
    using FunctionPtr = void(P<objectThread>::*)();
private:
    T_ptr getCompatibleFunctionPointer(FunctionPtr funcPtr) {}
    T_ptr m_t_ptr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. The only thing that seems weird is that you're using `P` as a class-template in your alias. In the snippet, `P` is not a template.

Anyway, this is what I use for member-function pointers:

```
template <typename Class, typename Ret, typename ... Args>
using MemFunPtr = Ret (Class::*)(Args ...);
```

You can use it like this:

```
struct A
{
    void fun(int, char) { cout << "whoop\n"; }
};


int main()
{
    MemFunPtr<A, void, int, char> m = &A::fun;

    A a;
    (a.*m)(5, 'a');
}
```